# Parsing problem on string and array using regular expressions, pattern matcher methods find() and group()

Tags: java, arrays, json, regex, parsing

I am using regular expressions to retrieve objects from a Json file that contain URLs, however unable to correctly pass results of m.group(1) into an array.

```
String[] googleArray =  Google.split("(?=https://)");         
System.out.println(googleArray[0] + "test"); 

however

googleArray[0] contains all of the links
googleArray[1] is already out of bounds
```

I have tried a number of options, and thus far I have been able to observe the following:

- (m.group(1)) prints to terminal/screen correctly, each URL in a separate line
- bw.write(m.group(1)) writing  to txt file results in a single string
- String google = (m.group(1))   System.out.println(Google) prints to - terminal/screen  correctly, each URL in a separate line
- bx.write(google) empty result when writing string google to txt file

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File fout = new File("out.txt");
    File fout1 = new File("out1.txt");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
    FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(fout1);



    URL a = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=eran+ariel&cx=006156390203515615519%3A-lsrgi-_9-o&key=AIzaSyAeDR4GlES4I2hwAbrifRiF7uUDi12pfaM");
    URLConnection yc = a.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    BufferedWriter bx = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos2));



    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            if (inputLine.trim().matches("\"link\": \"([^\"]+)\",")) {
             Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(": \"(.*)\",");
            matchPattern(inputLine, pattern, bw, bx);
       }

    }

   bw.close();
   in.close();


}

private static void matchPattern(String inputLine, Pattern pattern,  BufferedWriter bw,  BufferedWriter bx ) throws IOException {

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

    String google = null;
    while (m.find()) {

        //System.out.println(m.group(1));

        bw.write(m.group(1));
        google = m.group(1);


        //System.out.println(m.group(1));

    }


    System.out.println(google);
    bx.write(google);
    String[] googleArray =  google.split("(?=https://)");;
    System.out.println(googleArray[0] );





}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to remove "https://"?

Comment: no, the regex "looks ahead" in this context

Comment: Where do you close **bx**? You need to close this writer.

Comment: @Emma  the sample input would be a json file from which my desired outputs are queried from the tree structure, as in this case a set of URL's . The sum being the whole of its parts...